# Errors installing R

Tags: r

Hello yesterday I wanted to install the latest version of R 4.0.2 modifying

`sudo nano / etc / apt / sources.list`  I was able to install it but when trying packages like Tidyverse among others more complex it gave me an error so I decided to undo it. but I always install the same version regardless of the method it occupies, 4.0.2 is always installed.
i already removed  `r-base-core` and I would like to install version 3.6 where I can work, I already tried all the ways, but always version 4.0.2 returns with those errors, if someone could guide me to solve those errors or install that happy version with those packages that I need, I would really appreciate it

added already remove what you add to `sudo nano / etc / apt / sources.list`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Ubuntu or Ubuntu-based Linux, you can use apt-get to install a specific version of a package, see https://askubuntu.com/a/92021

Before you start, make sure that

- you uninstalled the r-base package (and other R packages you installed before) by running `sudo apt-get remove r-base` (repeat for every package)
- after restoring `sources.list` to the default, you run `sudo apt-get update` to sync

Next, you may want to check what versions of `r-base` are available in your registered repositories. Use the following command:

```
apt-cache madison r-base
```

This will show you a list of available versions. If version 3.6 is in the list, you can install this version using:

```
sudo apt-get install r-base=3.6
```

You need to replace `3.6` with the exact version string obtained via the `apt-cache madison` command (e.g., `3.6-1ubuntu1`)

If version 3.6 is not in the list of available versions, you need to add an additional repository to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file. The repo to add depends on your current Ubuntu version:

*eoan*: `deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu eoan-cran35/`

*bionic*: `deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/`

*xenial*: `deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial-cran35/`

*trusty*: `deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty-cran35/`

Note that these repos specifically contain the latest version 3.6, as explained at https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/

After adding the repo, run the following commands to complete the installation:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install r-base
```